# Which loop code is better practice?

Tags: python

```
def minval(xs):
    minum = xs[0]
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] < minum: #difference in code: xs[i]
            minum = xs[i]
    return minum
```

or

```
def minval(xs):
    minum = xs[0]
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if i < minum: #difference in code: i
            minum = xs[i]
    return minum
```

It gives me the same results:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print minval(lst)

1
```

Which one is better?
Why do they both give the same result?

Is there a better more shorter way to get the same result, without resorting to pythons own functions?

Edit:
I got it why it works, I ran the second one, it looped through the "i" which was just the numbers from the range of the len of xs and not the actual indexes of xs.

Comment: What's wrong with Python's built-in function [`min`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)?

Answer (score 4):

They aren't the same: The second gives `-1` for `[-1,-2,-3]` and is simply spuriously correct, while the first gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

A slight improvement would be:

```
def minval(xs):
    minimum = xs[0]
    for x in xs[1:]:
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    return minimum
```

In general you should loop through the values in a list rather than finding the range and then looping through the indices. If you really need the indices you can also use `enumerate`.

But as others have said, you would simply use `min` for this.